# CallScreeningService getExtras NULL on Android 10 API 29

Tags: android, bundle, phone-call, android-10.0

I am using the Android Class CallScreeningService onScreenCall(Call.Details calldetails) to get all incoming calls and everything works fine! From now I have an error, that on Android 10 devices the function calldetails.getExras() and calldetails.getIntentExtras() always returns NULL, instead of a Bundle, where I can read some further information. On Android 9 devices and older everything works fine.

Someone has a similar issue? Here is the Source Code and some Declarations:

```
public class IncomingCallService extends CallScreeningService {

    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
                if (callDetails.getExtras() != null) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Everything works on Android 9 or older");
                }else{
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Its Null on Android 10!");
                }  

                if (callDetails.getIntentExtras() != null) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Everything works on Android 9 or older");
                }else{
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Its Null on Android 10!");
                }     
}
```

And Manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".call_handler.IncomingCallService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Anyone has some information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android docs:

> Note: The Call.Details instance provided to a call screening service
>   will only have the following properties set. The rest of
>   the Call.Details properties will be set to their default value
>   or null.
>
> Call.Details#getCallDirection()
>
> Call.Details#getConnectTimeMillis()
>
> Call.Details#getCreationTimeMillis()
>
> Call.Details#getHandle()
>
> Call.Details#getHandlePresentation()
>
> Only calls where
>   the Call.Details#getHandle() Uri#getScheme() is PhoneAccount#SCHEME_TEL are
>   passed for call screening. Further, only calls which are not in the
>   user's contacts are passed for screening. For outgoing calls, no
>   post-dial digits are passed.

So what you are seeing it's just the expected behavior for Android 10.

Comment: Hi, ok thanks for your research and information! Great work!

Comment: On Androind 29+ you need user permission

Comment: How can I get here the phone number of the current device, that is used for the phone call? I want to determine which SIM card slot is used, and its relevant phone number.

Answer (score 0):

On Androind 29+ you need user permission :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```